# Injecting the Maharajah into the Barbarous Child's introduction

Tags: c#, strings, parsing

I'm building a random text generator!

My idea was to borrow slightly from the `string.Format` method styling, have a "format string" that controlled the overall construction of the string, and include "control string" segments inside them that classes will inject text into depending on their own logic.

For example, the input string:

> Before you stands {Person:FullName}.

Where `{Person:FullName}` expands to:

> {Prefix} {Name} {Postfix}, {Rank} of {Region:FullName}

Generates:

> Before you stands The Barbarous Pompey The Child, Maharajah of The The
>   Ephemeral Citystate of Charr.
>
> Before you stands Bertram The Churlish, Prefect of County of Dragons.
>
> Before you stands The Honourable Launce The Child, Pastor of The
>   Stormy Duchy of Key.
>
> Before you stands The Roguish Parolles The Holy, Grand Duke of Sands
>   of Avarice.
>
> Before you stands The Barbarous Dogberry The Great, Colonel of
>   Elvenhome.
>
> Before you stands The Cowardly Lysander The Sinner, Archon of
>   Principality of Elvenhome.
>
> Before you stands The Honourable Snug The Holy, Saopha of The Shining
>   Principality of Old Thatch.

**The code**

```
public class Parser
{
    private IControlStringMatcher matcher;

    public Parser(IControlStringMatcher matcher)
    {
        this.matcher = matcher;
    }

    public string Parse(string input)
    {
        var finder = new ControlStringFinder('{', ':', '}');

        var controlStrings = finder.FindAllControlStrings(input);

        string result = input;

        foreach (var controlString in controlStrings)
        {

            if (matcher.Matches(controlString))
            {
                var originalString = input.Substring(controlString.Index, controlString.Length);


                var newString = matcher.Match(controlString);

                result = result.Replace(originalString, newString);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

`Parser` is designed to split up the input string and stitch the replacement parts back together. It doesn't decide what goes where, that's up to the `IControlStringMatcher` instance.

```
public class ControlStringFinder
{
    private char controlStringStarter;
    private char controlStringTerminator;
    private char valueSeparator;

    public ControlStringFinder(char controlStringStarter, char valueSeparator, char controlStringTerminator)
    {
        this.controlStringStarter = controlStringStarter;
        this.valueSeparator = valueSeparator;
        this.controlStringTerminator = controlStringTerminator;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ControlString> FindAllControlStrings(string input)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == controlStringStarter)
            {
                var end = -1;

                for (var j = i + 1; j < input.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (input[j] == controlStringTerminator)
                    {
                        end = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (end == -1)
                {
                    throw new FormatException("Input string has opening control string starter with no matching control string terminator.");
                }

                var internalString = input.Substring(i + 1, end - i - 1);


                var values = new Queue<string>(internalString.Split(valueSeparator));

                yield return new ControlString(i, end - i + 1, values);

                i = end;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`ControlStringFinder` is a helper class that simply extracts all control strings from an input string.

```
public class ControlString
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public Queue<string> Values { get; set; }

    public ControlString(int index, int length, Queue<string> values)
    {
        this.Index = index;
        this.Values = values;
        this.Length = length;
    }

    public ControlString NextControlString
    {
        get
        {
            return new ControlString(Index + Values.Peek().Length, Length - Values.Peek().Length, new Queue<string>(Values.Skip(1)));
        }
    }

    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

A control string is a simple class containing data pertaining to the control strings found in the input string. Index refers to its position in the original string, to help the `Parser` work out where to make the replacement.

```
public interface IControlStringMatcher
{
    bool Matches(ControlString controlString);

    string Match(ControlString controlString);
}
```

Pretty simply interface for `IControlStringMatcher`, whether this control string can be replaced by the implementer, and the actual replacement itself.

```
public class ControlStringMatcherCollection : IControlStringMatcher
{
    public IEnumerable<IControlStringMatcher> ControlStringMatchers { get; set; }

    public ControlStringMatcherCollection(IEnumerable<IControlStringMatcher> controlStringMatchers)
    {
        this.ControlStringMatchers = controlStringMatchers;
    }

    public bool Matches(ControlString controlString)
    {
        return ControlStringMatchers.Any(x => x.Matches(controlString));
    }

    public string Match(ControlString controlString)
    {
        if (!Matches(controlString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument cannot be matched by this matcher.", "controlString");
        }

        return ControlStringMatchers.First(x => x.Matches(controlString)).Match(controlString);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class ContextControlStringMatcher : IControlStringMatcher
{
    public string Context { get; set; }

    public IControlStringMatcher Matcher { get; private set; }

    public ContextControlStringMatcher(string context, IControlStringMatcher matcher)
    {
        if(matcher == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("matcher");
        }

        this.Context = context;
        this.Matcher = matcher;
    }

    public bool Matches(ControlString controlString)
    {
        try
        {
            return controlString.Values.Peek().Equals(Context) && Matcher.Matches(controlString.NextControlString);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error processing controlString " + string.Join(":", controlString.Values.ToArray()));
            throw;
        }
    }

    public string Match(ControlString controlString)
    {
        if (!Matches(controlString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument cannot be matched by this matcher.", "controlString");
        }

        return Matcher.Match(controlString.NextControlString);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class FuncControlStringMatcher : IControlStringMatcher
{
    public Func<ControlString, bool> CanMatch { get; set; }

    public Func<ControlString, string> Matcher { get; set; }

    public FuncControlStringMatcher(Func<ControlString, string> matcher, Func<ControlString, bool> canMatch)
    {
        this.Matcher = matcher;
        this.CanMatch = canMatch;
    }

    public bool Matches(ControlString controlString)
    {
        return CanMatch(controlString);
    }

    public string Match(ControlString controlString)
    {
        if (!Matches(controlString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument cannot be matched by this matcher.", "controlString");
        }

        return Matcher(controlString);
    }
}
```

These three are the most common of the `IControlStringMatcher` instances.

The first, fairly simply, represents a collection of them and runs `Match` on the first instance that `Matches` returns a true for.

The second allows the navigation of control string context. For example, the control string `{Person:Name}` can be matched by a `ContextControlStringMatcher` instance with Context "Person". Doing so strips the string `Person` from the control string, and passes {Name} to the `ContextControlStringMatcher` instance's internal `IControlStringMatcher`.

The last allows you to pass `Func` instances for both `Match` and `Matches`. This is typically how I set up end-point values, instead of coding them into the methods themselves.

```
public class Person : IControlStringMatcher
{   
    public string prefix;
    public string name;
    public string rank;
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public string postfix;

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return new Parser(Matchers).Parse("{Prefix} {Name} {Postfix}, {Rank} of {Region:FullName}");
        }
    }

    public Pronoun Pronouns { get; set; }

    public ControlStringMatcherCollection Matchers { get; set; }

    public Person(Pronoun pronouns, Region region)
    {
        this.Pronouns = pronouns;
        this.Region = region;

        Matchers = new ControlStringMatcherCollection(new List<IControlStringMatcher>()
        {
            new ContextControlStringMatcher("Pronoun", Pronouns),
            new ValueControlStringMatcher("Prefix", ()=> prefix),
            new ValueControlStringMatcher("Postfix", ()=> postfix),
            new ContextControlStringMatcher("Region", Region),
            new ValueControlStringMatcher("Rank", ()=> rank),
            new ValueControlStringMatcher("Name", ()=> name),
            new ValueControlStringMatcher("FullName", ()=> FullName)
        });
    }

    public bool Matches(ControlString controlString)
    {
        return Matchers.Matches(controlString);
    }

    public string Match(ControlString controlString)
    {
        if (!Matches(controlString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument cannot be matched by this matcher.", "controlString");
        }

        return Matchers.Match(controlString);
    }
}
```

Here, `ValueControlStringMatcher` is a simple combination of a `ContextControlStringMatcher` and a `FuncControlStringMatcher` for ease of use.

Comment: Epic title! That's pretty awesome.

Comment: Nice title, but what question do you have ? ;-)

Comment: I guess my question would be: how badly have I coded this while sleep-deprived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a quick glance the `ControlStringFinder.FindAllControlStrings()` method  would benefit from the usage of the [`String.IndexOf(char, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
public IEnumerable<ControlString> FindAllControlStrings(string input)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == controlStringStarter)
        {
            var end = input.IndexOf(controlStringTerminator, i + 1);

            if (end == -1)
            {
                throw new FormatException("Input string has opening control string starter with no matching control string terminator.");
            }

            var internalString = input.Substring(i + 1, end - i - 1);

            var values = new Queue<string>(internalString.Split(valueSeparator));

            yield return new ControlString(i, end - i + 1, values);

            i = end;
        }
    }
}
```

---

To be on the safe side for changing accidentially the values of the `controlStringStarter`, `controlStringTerminator` or `valueSeparator` in the `ControlStringFinder` class you should make them `readonly`.

---

None of the properties of the classes needs to be public writeable. For encapsulation you should make the setters `private`.

---

Instead of throwing an `ArgumentException` with the same message 3 times I would suggest to throw a `MatchException` with an overloaded constructor which sets the message to this repeated value.

---

In its current state a consumer of the `Parser` class can't know what the values for `controlStringStarter`, `controlStringTerminator` or `valueSeparator` should be. Also, if you want to use other `chars` for this purpose you would need to change the `Parser` class.

This would be a good place to use properties with public getters **and** setters.

---

> ```
> public Person(Pronoun pronouns, Region region)
> ```

This looks strange. A parameter of a `Pronoun` type which is called `pronouns` which is indicating that it is more than one `Pronoun`. Better use the singular.

Comment: Spot on! Clearly I need more sleep before I code. In the case of `pronouns` I think perhaps I should rename the class to `Pronouns` because it contains a set of pronouns (e.g. he, him, his, etc) for different situations.